# How to add customized color letter in matplotlib?

Tags: colors, matplotlib

Matplotlib only defines below basic colors:

```
•b: blue
•g: green
•r: red
•c: cyan
•m: magenta
•y: yellow
•k: black
•w: white
```

And I want to define more custom color letters, such as

```
mc1 = RGB(164,106,228)
mc2 = RGB(220,170,114)
mc3 = RGB(249,85,132)
```

then I can define

```
my_color_list = ['g','r','y','b','c','m','k', 'mc1','mc2','mc3']
```

Then `my_color_list` can be use for below demo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dt = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_color_list = ['g','r','y','b','c','m','k', 'mc1','mc2','mc3'] # not valid 
bar(range(len(dt)),dt,color=my_color_list)
plt.show()
```

So how to define customize color letter in matplotlib ? Or, if I have a list of RGB tuple, how to combine RGB tuple together with basic color letters and assign to 'color' parameter of 'plot'/'bar' command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matplotlib supports many ways to specify the color.  In addition to the basic colors, you can use CSS color hex codes, Web color names and RGB values.

- Hex code: a Python string, e.g. `'#d2691e'`.
- Web color name: a Python string, e.g. `'chocolate'`.
- RGB values: a Python tuple, in the order of RGB: `(0.824, 0.412, 0.118)`.  The components should be normalized to fall within [0, 1].
- Greyscale: a Python string giving the greyscale, e.g. `'0.7'`.

Whenever a color is expected, these forms can be used just like the standard one-letter color names.

See: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html

Comment: I see. Thanks. I can do it as color_list = ['g','r','y','b','c','m','k',(0.976,0.333,0.518),(0.643,0.416,0.894),(0.863,0.667,0.447)]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to edit the matplotlib color list directly, using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors['mc1'] = (0.976,0.333,0.518)
```

I would be careful with this option, though, since it can break some useful matplotlib syntax. For instance, calling a color 'mo' might confuse it, since 'o' can mean the marker style and 'm' can mean magenta. Best to stick with single letters not currently used, like a, e-j, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can also define your own color dictionary as shown in the MWE below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

col = {'azure':(0.2,0.4,0.6), 'grey':(0.69,0.69,0.69), 'hotpink':(0.68,0.14,0.37), 'babyblue':(0.87,0.94,0.94)}

ch = 'grey'
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],color=col[ch])
plt.show()
```