# Registering named colors in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, it is possible to register colormaps, so that they can be easily used in the `cmap` argument of many plotting functions. Is there a way to also register named colors? For example, I'd like to be able to register my own color definitions and then use them as "my_blue", "my_red", "my_green", and so on...

My current solution is to have those color definitions in a json file, and import this file into every new script. However, it would be much more convenient if those colors were registered, so I wouldn't have to import the json file every time.

Thanks.

**UPDATE -- Temporary Solution:**

I have been able to register new named colors with the following steps:

1. `import matplotlib as mpl`;
2. Go to the directory `mpl.__path__`;
3. Create the file `_color_data_ext.py` containing the dictionary `NEW_COLORS` with the new color definitions (see file `_color_data.py` for an example);
4. In the file `colors.py`, include the following import statement to include the new dictionary: `from ._color_data_ext import NEW_COLORS` (this should be around line #58 right after `from _color_data import ...`);
5. Still in the file `colors.py`, include the new color definitions into the dictionary with all colors recognizable by matplotlib: `_colors_full_map.update(NEW_COLORS)` (this should be around line #77 right after `_colors_full_map` is initialized);
6. Restart your Python kernel to make sure that these changes take effect.

I know this solution is far from ideal, and it might need to be repeated whenever you update matplotlib to a new version. But it works! Hopefully someone else will provide a more permanent solution.

Comment: Since you don't want to do it in the script (presumably exactly what you are doing with register_cmap already), where do you want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is one of the solution listed as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302079/how-to-add-customized-color-letter-in-matplotlib).

IMO, the most reasonable option is a color dictionary or simply to declare your colors as variables somewhere (e.g. `mycolors.py`) and import them:

```py
my_blue = "#1030f0"
my_red = "#ee0000"
...
```

then `from mycolors import my_blue, my_red`.

But if for some reason you really want them registered in matplotlib (again, not sure this is a good idea), you could use [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626339/5962321)