# Create new named color in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a few colors I use over and over again in my work.  I would like to "register" these as named colors in Matplotlib (by executing code in my work, not by changing the source of Matplotlib in my install) so that they can be referred to by string in the way any "included" color can be.

For example, I want to be able to say `my_favorite_blue = '#76c4db'` and then run `plt.plot(range(5), range(5), color='my_favorite_blue')` and have it work.

I don't mind if the solution is ugly.  But would like to be able to run something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def register_new_color(name, value):
    *** your brilliance goes here***

register_new_color('my_favorite_blue', '#76c4db')

plt.plot(range(5), range(5), color='my_favorite_blue')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a bit "pry under the hood"-ish:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mpc

def register_color(color_name, color_spec):
    mpc._colors_full_map[color_name] = color_spec
    return mpc._colors_full_map
```

I think that'll do it.  And should deal with the annoying caching matplotlib has on that `_colors_full_map` variable, which pretends to be a dictionary in most cases, but actually caches semi-transparent calculated colors since it's a `_ColorMapping`.

I don't really like this.  But it works.  Can anyone suggest something better, or that doesn't require getting under the hood?

Comment: VERY interesting. I wonder if _returning_ the  `_ColorMapping` is necessary, or it's something that you placed there "just in case".

Comment: I put it there so I could audit my work.  I.e. it blasts the newly-updated _ColorMapping instance on the screen (or assigned to a variable) so I could inspect whether or not I got this right.  As you implied, the `return` statement isn't needed to actually get this working.

Answer (score 0):

If you say `light_blue="#76c4db"` and run `plt.plot(..., color=light_blue)` it will work, as `color=` can take in the hex string stored in `light_blue`. You wouldn't need a `register_new_color()` function in this case.

---

It's possible to register colormaps in `matplotlib`, but not individual colours as far as I know. Here's a method that uses colormap registration to attempt a solution.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import colormaps as cmaps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Wrap the desired color in a colourmap object
custom_blue_cm = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_blue', ['#76c4db']*2)
#Register the new colormap
cmaps.register(cmap=custom_blue_cm)

#Example usage
plt.plot(range(5), range(5),
         color=cmaps['custom_blue'](0))
```

This SO post describes a more hacky method, but results might be closer to what you want: [Registering named colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73423618/21896093)

Comment: I appreciate that will work.  But I explicitly want (for the convenience of other users in my environment) to be able to refer to my color by a string name, and not a variable name.

Comment: I see. I've updated my post with an attempt that uses colormap registration to effectively register an individual colour.